# Appcelerator Studio apps does not run after El Capitan Update. Invalid Request on compile

Tags: appcelerator

As the title says, After I have updated my OS to El Capitan all my apps on Appcelerator Studio does not build successfully anymore. Even newly created sample apps does not build. I only get a very generic error message from the console.

My app is targeted for iOS and Android and it does not work for both. I get the same error message as below.

```
[INFO] :   ----- OPTIMIZING -----
[INFO] :   - android/alloy.js
[INFO] :   - android/alloy/sync/localStorage.js
[INFO] :   - android/alloy/sync/properties.js
[INFO] :   - android/alloy/sync/sql.js
[INFO] :   
[INFO] :   Alloy compiled in 1.48612s
[INFO] :   Alloy compiler completed successfully
[ERROR] :  invalid request
```

How to resolve this? I already tried to project clean multiple times.

Comment: Install Studio again by removing the hidden folders in users root directory.

Hidden folders are .appcelerator and .titanium

Answer (score 55, accepted):

That has nothing to deal with the operating system.

Solution;

1. Open terminal
2. appc logout
3. appc login

Ta dah! - solved :-)